# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 02:05

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-2.7

I have some dates in a json files, and I am searching for those who corresponds to today's date :

```
import  os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

input_file  = file(FILE, "r")
j = json.loads(input_file.read().decode("utf-8-sig"))

os.environ['TZ'] = 'CET'

for item in j:
    lt = time.strftime('%A %d %B')
    st = item['start']
    st = datetime.strptime(st, '%A %d %B')

    if st == lt :
        item['start'] = datetime.strptime(st,'%H:%M')
```

I had an error like this :

```
File "/home/--/--/--/app/route.py", line 35, in file.py

st = datetime.strptime(st, '%A %d %B')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime

data_string[found.end():])

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 02:05
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The value of `st` at `st = datetime.strptime(st, '%A %d %B')` line something like `01 01 2013 02:05` and the `strptime` can't parse this. Indeed, you get an hour in addition of the date... You need to add `%H:%M` at your strptime.

Comment: I got the same error when I had swapped the month and date variables by accident. It was showing `unconverted data remains: 3`. I thought 3 was a unit, but it was simply the part of the string leftover after the parser had finished.

Comment: I have the same error parsing "09 Dec 2020 11:33:28 AM" with the format "%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p". baffles me.

Comment: For me it was unconverted data remains: 8 and it was about the milliseconds !
This comment's section helped me figure out the problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 32):

Best answer is to use the `from dateutil import parser`.

usage:

```
from dateutil import parser
datetime_obj = parser.parse('2018-02-06T13:12:18.1278015Z')
print datetime_obj
# output: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 6, 13, 12, 18, 127801, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: Sometimes it's can be really useful, but keep in mind that this solution usually works several times slower.

Comment: Loved it! Simple and straight forward. I was in a situation where I had to parse the date from string which could assume any datetime format. This one was awesome!

Answer (score 9):

You have to parse *all* of the input string, you cannot just ignore parts.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

for item in j:
    st = datetime.strptime(item['start'], '%A %d %B %H:%M')

    if st.date() == date.today():
        item['start'] = st.time()
```

Here, we compare the date to today's date by using more `datetime` objects instead of trying to use strings.

The alternative is to only pass in *part* of the `item['start']` string (splitting out just the time), but there really is no point here, not when you could just parse everything in one step first.

Comment: I think that if %z were part of that timestamp, then the alternative would be necessary because the timezone is not handled.

Answer (score 3):

Well it was very simple. I was missing the format of the date in the json file, so I should write :

```
st = datetime.strptime(st, '%A %d %B %H %M')
```

because in the json file the date was like :

```
"start": "Friday 06 December 02:05",
```

Comment: You are missing the `:` there. You are also missing out on the richness of the `datetime` object that you parsed out by trying to compare it to strings.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I use the richness of datetime in this context? Thanks anyway .

Comment: See my answer, where I use `st.date() == date.today()` to test if the parsed value is today instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
  timeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 335, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

In my case, the problem was an extra space in the input date string. So I used `strip()` and it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

just cut the string that match the format, do something like:

```
st = datetime.strptime(st[:-6], '%A %d %B')
```

Answer (score 0):

**ValueError: unconverted data remains: 02:05** means that part of your date including time is not in the **datetime.strptime** used pattern my suggestion is to make simple trick and check if your string date has time or not eg. `len(date_string) > 10`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_strings = ['2022-12-31 02:05:00', '2022-12-31', '2023-01-01 05:30:00', '2023-01-01']

dates = []
for date_string in date_strings:
    if len(date_string) > 10:
        # String has time information
        date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    else:
        # String has no time information
        date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
    dates.append(date)

print(dates)
```