# Manipulating each item (string) in a list, within a list, within a list

Tags: python, list

*Using python 3 on Python 3.6.4 on Windows

```
twoDlist = [
    [] * len(pathology_case_retrieval_report[1:])
    for x in range(len(pathology_case_retrieval_report[1:]))
]
```

This is my list of length 67.

```
for i in range(len(twoDlist)):
    temp = twoDlist[i]
    temp.append(SPnumsList[i])
    temp.append(requested_ByList[i])
    temp.append(dateTimelist1[i])
    twoDlist[i] = temp
```

This is how I appended each item from each list (`SPnumsList`, `requested_ByList` and `dateTimelist1`) to each list inside of larger list (`twoDlist`).

Example element inside of twoDlist:

```
['Number', 'Physician Name', ['stringN']]
```

*Please note that the 2nd index of this list can have 0 to n number of elements inside and I would like to account for this.

I need to perform string manipulation (via regular expression on each element in 2nd index (specifically `re.sub(r'[A-Za-z.\'\"\,\n;:]', '', stringN)`).
And then append the new item back to the 2nd index of the list, replacing the the old string.

I would also like to: 
take each `stringN` element in

```
['123', 'Dr. Bob', ['string1','string2', 'string3']]
```

and append it to a new list while keeping the `'Number'` and `'Physician Name'`.

Example of how I would like my data to look like:

```
[
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string1'],
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string2'],
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string3'],
    # ...
]
```

for each `['Number', 'Physician Name', ['stringN']]` in `twoDlist`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty concisely using `reduce` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)) to split up each record into multiple for each string in the list of strings at index 2. On each iteration you can also perform your regex substitution.

Here is an example:

```
import re
from functools import reduce

twoDlist = [
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', ['string1','string2', 'string3']],
    ['456', 'Dr. Jim', ['string4','string5', 'string6']],
]

regex = r'[A-Za-z.\'\"\,\n;:]'

final = reduce(
    lambda a, sublist: a + [[*sublist[:2], re.sub(regex, "", st)] for st in sublist[2]],
    twoDlist,
    []
)
```

`reduce` iterates over `twoDlist` and each element (`sublist`) of `twoDlist` is converted into a list of lists—one for each element of the list at index 2—using a list comprehension. Then these new lists are all appended onto the list processed so far.

The result is `final` as:

```
[
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', '1'],
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', '2'],
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', '3'],
    ['456', 'Dr. Jim', '4'],
    ['456', 'Dr. Jim', '5'],
    ['456', 'Dr. Jim', '6']
]
```

Comment: Thanks Henry Woody. It worked. I need to become more familiar with the reduce function!

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi Check out the docs on `reduce` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce It's a really powerful function that can used in a bunch of different ways

Comment: The lambda function takes two arguments: a and sublist. I understand that sublist refers to list elements in twoDlist. What does "a" refer to? Thank you

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi `a` is the total so far. On the first iteration, `a` takes the initial value given (the last arg to `reduce`) of `[]`. For each successive iteration `a` is equal to the return value of the `lambda` function from the previous iteration. Note also that the first argument need not be a `lambda` function, it can be any function but `lambdas` are often used because these are generally one-off functions

Comment: I’ve been reading up on the doc for the reduce function... would the empty list be considered as the initializer?

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi exactly

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi a common use for `reduce` is to reduce a list numbers by summing them (hence the name), which can be done with `reduce(lambda a,x: a + x, my_list, 0)`. Our example is semantically different, as the list ends up longer at the end (not a reduction), but the process is the same.

Comment: Would it have been possible to use the map() function to map the lambda on the ith element of every list element in my twoDlist?

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi nearly. The difference is that `map` (pretty much equivalent to a list comprehension) returns only one element for each in the original list. So in this example, you can split each sublist into three, but they would all need to be placed in a containing list. So you end up with an extra layer of nesting. In contrast, `reduce` can change the number of elements in the main list (or convert to some other datatype entirely)

Comment: twoDlist = [
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', ['1336/08/02/18', '1406/08/02/18']],
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', ['1336/08/02/18', '1406/08/02/18']],
    ['123', 'Dr. Bob', ['1336/08/02/18', '1406/08/02/18']]
    
]   I am trying to use the same code that you provided before to turn these strings objects to datetime objects... but I keep getting a ValueError: unconverted data remains: 17. Here is the code that I used: format = '%H%M/%d/%m/%y'
twoDlist3 = reduce(lambda a, sublist: a + [[*sublist[:2], datetime.strptime(string, format)] for string in sublist[2]], twoDlist2, [])

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi hmm that example works fine for me, but that error comes from parsing the datetimes as strings so its from `strptime` rather than the `reduce` logic. Check this post for help on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327937/valueerror-unconverted-data-remains-0205

Comment: Last question :) I'm still having trouble understanding the syntax of the list comprehension [[*sublist[:2], re.sub(regex, "", st)] for st in sublist[2]]. What exactly is being unpacked in *sublist[:2]?

Comment: @UwadiaEdomwonyi `sublist[:2]` contains all of `sublist` up to index 2. On the first iteration this will be `['123', 'Dr. Bob']`. Note that `*sublist[:2]` is equivalent to `sublist[0], sublist[1]`, but is more concise and easier to generalize

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
twoDlist = [['123', 'Dr. Bob', ['string1','string2', 'string3']], ['345', 'Dr. Joe', ['string4', 'string5']]]
```

you can issue

```
>>> [[[*sub[:-1], x] for x in sub[-1]] for sub in twoDlist]
[[['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string1'],
  ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string2'],
  ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string3']],
 [['345', 'Dr. Joe', 'string4'],
  ['345', 'Dr. Joe', 'string5']]]
```

If you additionally want to remove one level of nesting, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
>>> tmp = ([[*sub[:-1], x] for x in sub[-1]] for sub in twoDlist)
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(tmp))
[['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string1'],
 ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string2'],
 ['123', 'Dr. Bob', 'string3'],
 ['345', 'Dr. Joe', 'string4'],
 ['345', 'Dr. Joe', 'string5']]
```

Comment: Thank you timgeb!