# Python ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Tags: python, time

I have the following code:

This is my Code:

```
print (start_timestamp)
start_timestamp_no_iso = datetime.strptime(start_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

This is what I get:

```
INFO - 2018-11-20T14:44:03.452131
INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO - File "/home/ubuntu/script.py", line 84, in <module>
INFO - start_timestamp_no_iso = datetime.strptime(start_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
INFO - File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
INFO - tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
INFO - File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
INFO - data_string[found.end():])
INFO - ValueError: unconverted data remains:
INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

I understand what it means but I don't understand why it happens. I simply convert the timestamp from iso format to non iso. What is the problem?

Comment: whats `%dT` in the formatting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: unconverted data remains: 02:05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327937/valueerror-unconverted-data-remains-0205)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your format string `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f` is absolutely correct. I am sure, you have `line feeds` at the end of your line. Try

```
start_timestamp_no_iso = datetime.strptime(start_timestamp.strip(' \t\r\n'), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `start_timestamp.strip()` be sufficient? (Using the default strip behavior)

Comment: It would, just prefer **explicit** form to highlight suspected characters for the answer.