# How to handle nanoseconds with datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to modify an existing Python script which someone wrote to parse and view binary .dat files. The old logging format was
`log.2021-01-08.210025.dat`.

The new logs are now `log.2021-01-08.210025.718691.dat`.

I've tried to modify the below line of code but still receive errors. Can somebody explain to me what could be wrong?

```
filetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(m.group(3), '%Y-%m-%d.%H%M%S')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .277195
begin: 2021-01-07 21:00:25
end: 2021-01-07 21:00:40
```

Comment: Probably make sure the nanoseconds bit is not included in `m.group(3)`, if you don't really care about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: unconverted data remains: 02:05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327937/valueerror-unconverted-data-remains-0205)

Comment: Those are microseconds, not nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

The format you're specifying in `strptime` doesn't match the data you're passing from the regular expression. Your format is `'%Y-%m-%d.%H%M%S'` so it doesn't know what to do with the left over nanosecond info - hence the error "unconverted data remains"

Note that Python's datetime doesn't support nanosecond precision. But it does support microsecond (6 decimals) which appears to match what you have there

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-08.210025.718691', '%Y-%m-%d.%H%M%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8, 21, 0, 25, 718691)
```

See the Python documentation on format specifiers for info about the `%f` microsecond field, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Hi Peter - I tried that before and it wasn't working. I needed to add that to a couple of other lines of code and it worked!! - Thanks again :)